# Command file (when double clicked) doesn't work if this code is not inserted...why?

Tags: bash, macos, exec, nohup

When I double click on my .command file, it reads every line until it hits the `nohup` command which terminates the application (**Terminal**) as it runs in the background.

Now, when entering this command below at the top of the script, the whole script works. Why on earth would that be happening?

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>/Users/$username/Desktop/log.out 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Apperently when I'm running this command in the script:

```
nohup osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "'"$DIR"'"' & pkill -f -a Terminal
```

Terminating the application with pkill creates issues for the overall script. Thus, disrupting the `SIGHUP` signal. My solution is the following...

```
trap '' 1 # this blocks sighup so we don't die when terminal is closed
```

Thanks to *izabera* from [Freenode Chat](http://webchat.freenode.net/) - #bash channel.